# tightvncserver: How do I connect via SSH/Encryption?

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc, tightvnc

I am running `tightvncserver` on my Linux computer in my home network.

I connect to it using a Mac (also on the home network), currently running `Real VNC Viewer`. When I connect, I am notified that the connection is unencrypted.

It is my understanding that `tightvncserver` supports SSH. I have generated a pair of SSH keys that I use for these two computers.

How can I connect to the VNC server via SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tunnel the vnc port via ssh like this:

```
 ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@host.com
```

then, while leaving the terminal window open, on the client machine connect to localhost with your real vnc viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the target computer using SSH and forward the ports needed for VNC from the localhost to the target computer, then connect to those ports on the localhost, and communication will be encrypted in the SSH tunnel. The VNC client might still claim that data is unencrypted because it might not be aware of the SSH tunneling.